# My Nextjs app cannot run due to unsupported engine

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js

Upon installing next app using npx create-next-app blog-next

I recieve this error:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'next@12.0.4',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=12.22.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.16.3', npm: '7.24.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

```
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'next@12.0.4',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=12.22.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.16.3', npm: '7.24.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

I have used NVM :
`nvm install v12.22.0`

However the default npm still sets itself to 12.6.3
I have downloaded/updated / removed package lock etc...

Any thoughts on how to fix this issue globally so I do not encounter this again. I have never encountered this previously....
Thanks!